# How Do I Set Up LLMPredictor To Be able To Create Indexes?

Tags: python, indexing, chatbot, chatgpt-api

I am following along with this video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EE1Y2enHrcU) making a ChatGPT bot. Everything was fine until I the very end where I am trying to create the model and indexes for the bot.

I copied the code directly from the video creator's notebook `

```
def construct_index(directory_path):
    # set maximum input size
    max_input_size = 4096
    # set number of output tokens
    num_outputs = 256
    # set maximum chunk overlap
    max_chunk_overlap = 20
    # set chunk size limit
    chunk_size_limit = 600

    # define LLM (ChatGPT gpt-3.5-turbo)
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=num_outputs))
    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)
 
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()
    
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(
        documents, llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper
    )

    index.save_to_disk('index.json')

    return index


def ask_me_anything(question):

    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')
    response = index.query(question, response_mode="compact")

    display(Markdown(f"You asked: <b>{question}</b>"))
    display(Markdown(f"Bot says: <b>{response.response}</b>"))
```

This code runs without any problems

When I run this code:

```
construct_index('/data/notebook_files/textdata')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  at cell 32, line 1
  at cell 31, line 17, in construct_index(directory_path)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/llama_index/indices/vector_store/vector_indices.py, line 69, in __init__(self, nodes, index_struct, service_context, vector_store, **kwargs)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/llama_index/indices/vector_store/base.py, line 54, in __init__(self, nodes, index_struct, service_context, vector_store, use_async, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'llm_predictor'
```

I also tried it directly in the video creators notebook and got the same error. Is there something I am missing? What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the gpt_index module.

```
pip install gpt_index==0.4.24 --user
```